# How to specify the y-axis range for multiple y-axes in React Vis js

Tags: javascript, react-vis

So an overview of the issue I'm encountering is I have two y-axes on my chart and I need to change the domain range of each axis separately. So far I have not found anything that can do this within React Vis.

What I am looking for is a way to set the range of each axis separately, I know that `<XYPlot yDomain=[0,100]> </XYPlot>` will set the range for the y-axis but it sets it for both the y-axes on the chart. I need a way to do this separately for each of the y-axes as they corresponded to different plotted data on the chart.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question within  there is a yDomain in which you can set the range of that specific YAxis. For example, if you had two y-axes of different ranges you could do this.

`<YAxis orientation="left" yDomain={[0,100]} />`
`<YAxis orientation="right" yDomain={[0,250]} />`